# Run macro by clicking away from any ActiveX textbox in a document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm looking for a VBA script that will run whenever I click away from any of ActiveX textboxes in the document. Another alternative would be to have it run whenever I click on any textbox (without clicking away).

How can it be done without assigning subs to each textbox individually?

Answer (score 0):

Double click on your textbox and it will bring up the default method for that textbox, which in my testing is Textbox1_Change(). This method will run every time you type anything into the textbox.

You see two dropdown boxes at the top of the vba editor. Drop down on the one on the right and you'll see all the other available methods for the textbox, one of which is LostFocus which I reckon will suit your purposes. Clicking on that creates a sub that will execute every time the textbox loses focus. See how you go with that. Cheers

Comment: Just saw that your question was 'without assigning subs to each textbox individually'. As far as I know this is not possible.